# Getting Task Serialization exception when trying to publish to Kafka

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am executing a Spark Streaming job and I want to publish my result_dstream which is type of DStream[GenericData.Record] , so I used the code below for that purpose , but getting Task Not serializable Exception

```
val prod_props : Properties = new Properties()
prod_props.put("bootstrap.servers" , "localhost:9092")
prod_props.put("key.serializer" , "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
prod_props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer")

val _producer : KafkaProducer[String , Array[Byte]] = new KafkaProducer(prod_props)

result_DStream.foreachRDD(r => {
  r.foreachPartition(it => {
    while(it.hasNext)
      {
        val schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(schema_string)
        val recordInjection : Injection[GenericRecord , Array[Byte]] = GenericAvroCodecs.toBinary(schema)
        val record : GenericData.Record = it.next()
        val byte : Array[Byte] = recordInjection.apply(record)
        val prod_record : ProducerRecord[String , Array[Byte]] = new ProducerRecord("sample_topic_name_9" , byte)
        _producer.send(prod_record)
      }
  })
})
```

What can I do to solve this problem? I have tried suggestion like use the not serializable class in lambda function and use foreachPartition instead of foreach , and the problem is according to me is in `schema` or in `recordInjection`.

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:304)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:294)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2062)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:919)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:918)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreachPartition(RDD.scala:918)
at HadoopMetrics_Online$$anonfun$main$3.apply(HadoopMetrics_Online.scala:187)
at HadoopMetrics_Online$$anonfun$main$3.apply(HadoopMetrics_Online.scala:186)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:661)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:661)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:426)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:224)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:224)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:224)
at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:223)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer
Serialization stack:
- object not serializable (class: org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer, value: org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer@252f5489)
- field (class: HadoopMetrics_Online$$anonfun$main$3, name: _producer$1, type: class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer)
- object (class HadoopMetrics_Online$$anonfun$main$3, <function1>)
- field (class: HadoopMetrics_Online$$anonfun$main$3$$anonfun$apply$1, name: $outer, type: class HadoopMetrics_Online$$anonfun$main$3)
- object (class HadoopMetrics_Online$$anonfun$main$3$$anonfun$apply$1, <function1>)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:101)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:301)
... 30 more
```

Comment: Adding stacktrace would help

Comment: Added the stacktrace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`KafkaProducer` isn't serializable, and you're closing over it in your `foreachPartition` method. You'll need to declare it internally:

```
resultDStream.foreachRDD(r => {
  r.foreachPartition(it => {
    val producer : KafkaProducer[String , Array[Byte]] = new KafkaProducer(prod_props)
    while(it.hasNext) {
        val schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(schema_string)
        val recordInjection : Injection[GenericRecord , Array[Byte]] = GenericAvroCodecs.toBinary(schema)
        val record : GenericData.Record = it.next()
        val byte : Array[Byte] = recordInjection.apply(record)
        val prod_record : ProducerRecord[String , Array[Byte]] = new ProducerRecord("sample_topic_name_9" , byte)
        producer.send(prod_record)
      }
  })
})
```

Side note - Scala naming conventions are camelCase for variable names, not snake_case.

Comment: How can I know in future that which classes' object is troubling.

Comment: @JSR29 Spark has a `ClosureCleaner`, which gives you the exact field which is causing the problem, read the stacktrace: `object not serializable (class: org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer, value: org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer@252f5489)`